# IPN + mysql for paypal not verifying

Tags: php, mysql, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been working on this file for awhile and I'm just really baffled. I don't know what I'm doing wrong for the payment to not update user's coins and insert transactions into mySQL.

I've used the test tools on sandbox paypal to test the IPN and it returns successful. If I'm leaving out any other information - let me know.

my config.php (which just connects to mysql database)

```
<?php
session_start();
  include("database.php");
  if(!(@mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass") && @mysql_select_db("$tablename"))) {
?>
```

here is my IPN.php

```
<?php
require("config.php");

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
$pack = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `c_pack` WHERE `name`='{$item_name}' AND `coins`='{$item_number}'"));
$user = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$custom}'"));
if (
    ($receiver_email == $site->paypal) &&
    ($payment_amount == $pack->price) &&
    ($payment_status == 'Completed')
    ) {
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins`=`coins`+'{$pack->coins}' WHERE `id`='{$custom}'");          
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactions` (user, points, pack, money, date) VALUES('{$user->login}', '{$pack->coins}', '{$item_name}', '{$payment_amount}', NOW())");
}
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAHA stupid me, needed to put ssl://sandbox.paypal.com - this is for future reference for anyone else.. remember to setup your button and fp to sandbox. Took me 5 hours to figure this out.

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```